# My file output is being duplicated. Every new println includes all the previous. (Code included) 

Tags: java, file, io

**Exactly what I'm doing,**

```
    FileOutputStream out;
    PrintStream outputfile;
    try{
        out = new FileOutputStream("Project1.txt");
        outputfile = new PrintStream(out);
        int a[ ] = { 4, -3, 5, -2, -1, 2, 6, -2 };
        int maxSum;
        Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
        //Setup table column titles
        outputfile.println(fmt.format("%12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s%n", "Algorithm", "n", "time", "time/n^3", "time/n^2", "time/(n*log(n))"));
        outputfile.println(fmt.format("%12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s%n%n", "_________", "_", "(ms)", "x100,000", "x10,000", "x10,000"));
        // Algorithm 1
        for( int n = 256; n <= 2049; n *= 2 ){
            int alg = 1;
            long timing;
            maxSum = maxSubSum1( a );
            timing = getTimingInfo( n, alg );
            double time = (((double)timing)/1000000.0);
            outputfile.println(fmt.format("%12s %12d %12f %12f %12f %12f%n", "Alg. 1", n, time, (time/(((long)n)*n*n))*100000.0, (time/(n*n))*10000, (time/((double)n*Math.log((double)n)))*10000));   
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          System.err.println("Error in writing to file");
        }
```

**Some output I am getting that I am referring to,**

> ```
>    Algorithm            n         time     time/n^3     time/n^2   time/(n*log(n))
>
>    Algorithm            n         time     time/n^3     time/n^2   time/(n*log(n))
>    _________            _         (ms)     x100,000      x10,000   x10,000
>
>
>    Algorithm            n         time     time/n^3     time/n^2   time/(n*log(n))
>    _________            _         (ms)     x100,000      x10,000   x10,000
>
>    Alg. 1              256     4.335838     0.025844     0.661596  30.543418
> ```

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild More code has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.format()` instead of `fmt.format()`. Or call `Formatter`'s constructor with `out` and remove the `outputfile.println()` calls:

```
out = new FileOutputStream("Project1.txt");
Formatter fmt = new Formatter(out);
fmt.format("%12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s%n", 
    "Algorithm", "n", "time", "time/n^3", "time/n^2", "time/(n*log(n))");
fmt.format("%12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s%n%n", 
    "_________", "_", "(ms)", "x100,000", "x10,000", "x10,000");

...
fmt.flush();
out.close();
```

A `new Formatter()` (created with noarg constructor) use an internal `StringBuilder` and appends every results of `format()` calls to it. Furthermore, every `format()` returns the `formatter` object itself (`return this;`). Then `outputfile.println()` calls the returned `formatter`'s `toString()` method which returns the whole content of the internal `StringBuilder`. So, any subsequent calls of `format()` increases the `StringBuilder`'s size and you print the whole buffer after every `format()` call.

Comment: I used fmt and had a blank file.

Comment: I've updated my answer. An `fmt.flush()` is needed at end of the method.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are making it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
out.printf("%s%n", "A");
out.printf("%s%n", "B");
```

or

```
out.println("A");
out.println("B");
```

outputs

```
A
B
```

Comment: Could you be more clear as to why you don't think my code is working? I added more so maybe it could assist you in helping me. Thanks @Peter

Comment: @KRB, The code you have will only produce the header once. You are don't doing what you think you are doing.  I suggest you use a debugger to step through the code so you can see why the header appears more than once.

Answer (score 1):

When you construct a new `Formatter`, the destination of the formatted output is a `StringBuilder`. Therefore, every time you call `outputfile.println(...)`, the current content of the `StringBuilder` is flushed to the output stream.

To fix this problem, all you need to do is this:

`Formatter fmt = new Formatter(out);`

fmt.format("%12s %12s %12s %12s %12s %12s%n", "Algorithm", "n", "time", "time/n^3", "time/n^2", "time/(n*log(n))");

Notice that you will not need to use a `PrintStream` object any more.

Comment: this leaves me with a blank file